EntityPropertyNotFoundError: Property was not found in "Gateway". Make sure your query is correct
Version @nestjs/typeorm:10.0.2
An error occurs despite the correctness. On an earlier version of typeorm everything worked correctly. I don’t want to roll back to the previous version, is there a fix? my ideas have run out.
let pairConfig = await this.pairSettingsRepository.findOne({
      where: [
        { from: from, to: to, type: PairType.CUSTOM, gateway: gateway },
        { from: from, to: to, type: PairType.DEFAULT },
        { from: from, to: 'EMPTY', type: PairType.DEFAULT },
        { from: 'EMPTY', to: to, type: PairType.DEFAULT },
      ],
      order: { gateway: 'ASC' },
      relations: { gateway: true },
    });

pairSettingsRepository
@Entity()
@Index(['from', 'to', 'type'], { unique: true, where: `type = 'default'` })
@Index(['from', 'to', 'gateway'], {
  unique: true,
  where: `'gatewayId' is not null`,
})
export class PairSettings<T = any> {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @ManyToOne(type => Gateway, { nullable: true })
  gateway: Gateway;

  @Column('text')
  from: string;

  @Column('text')
  to: string;

  @Column('text', { default: PairType.DEFAULT })
  type: PairType;

  @ManyToOne(type => RatesProvider, {
    eager: true,
    nullable: false,
  })
  ratesProvider: RatesProvider<T>;

  @Column('smallint', { default: 8 })
  precision: number;

  @Column('boolean', { default: true })
  doCalculateSpread: boolean;

  @Column('double precision', { default: 0 })
  spreadPercent: number;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;
}

Gateway repository
@Entity()
export class Gateway {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  name: string;

  @Column()
  apiKey: string;

  @Column({ type: 'boolean', default: true })
  isEnabled: boolean;

  @Column('boolean', { default: false })
  doCalculateSpread: boolean;

  @Column('double precision', { default: 0 })
  fiatSpreadPercent: number;

  @Column('double precision', { default: 0 })
  cryptoSpreadPercent: number;

  @OneToMany(
    type => PairSettings,
    pairSettings => pairSettings.gateway,
    { nullable: true },
  )
  pairSettings: PairSettings[];

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;
}


I tried different ways to make a query to the database
